# How to Combine a TF_IDF Vectorizer with a Custom Feature

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, data-science

I am trying to construct a model with a combination of numerical features from a dataframe and text features from a dataframe. However, I am having a lot of trouble successfully combining the features, training using the features, then testing the the features.

Right now I am trying to use a DataFrameMapper like so:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper


mapper = DataFrameMapper([
     ('body', TfidfVectorizer()),
     ('numeric_feature', None),

 ]) 

for train_index, test_index in kFold.split(DF['body']):

    # Split the dataset by Kfold

    X_train = even_rand[['body','numeric_feature']].iloc[train_index]
    y_train = even_rand['sub_class'].iloc[train_index]


    X_test = even_rand[['body','numeric_feature']].iloc[test_index]
    y_test = even_rand['sub_class'].iloc[test_index]

    # Vectorize/transform docs

    X_train = mapper.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test = mapper.fit_transform(X_test)



    # Get SVM
    svm = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2',
                                            alpha=1e-3, n_iter=5, random_state=10)
    svm.fit(X_train, y_train)
    svm_score = svm.score(X_test, y_test)
```

This successfully combines the data and trains the data, however when I try to test the data, the features don't seem to match up correctly, and I get the error

> ValueError: X has 49974 features per sample; expecting 87786

Would anyone know how to solve this issue or know of a better way to combine/train/test the numerical and text features together? I would also like to keep the features as sparse matrixes if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
X_train = mapper.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = mapper.fit_transform(X_test)
```

try:

```
X_train = mapper.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = mapper.transform(X_test) # change fit_transform to transform
```

Comment: @walker_4 For sparse output use `sparse` param in mapper initialization like `DataFrameMapper( ..., sparse=True)`